# GoogleAPI added but MapActivity becomes unseen

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, eclipse-plugin

I have a little problem with googlemap application that I would like to use this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) to work with my Eclipse, I have updated all Elipse ADTs, downloaded GoogleAPI but I still have got an error from the IDE that MapActivity from which my HelloWorld Application is to be extended can not be resolved to a type. Am I missing some important imports or settings I need to perform on the Eclipse itself to make it work ?

```
public class HelloGoogleMapActivity extends MapActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @override
    protected boolean isRoundDisplayed()
    {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        MapView mapv=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapv.setBuildInZoomControls(true);
    }
}
```

Also the first "@override" keyword is reported as illegal, which I have no idea why.

[**UPDATE**]

All the answers offered are correct. And the most correct one is a comment below. Thank you for your code snips. Cool!

Comment: Have you changed your project target to any google api X instead of any android X?

Comment: Also chk ur sdk installation on eclipse is proper or not ?

Answer (score 1):

for @Override exception jst change once javacompiler from your project properties ...JDK Compliance 1.6 to 1.5 and thn again set it to 1.6...i was facing the same prob.. it is bcz of some jdk build project...or eclipse prob...

And for map Prob

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/showmap"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:apiKey="@string/mapkey"
        android:clickable="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity.java

```
MapView mapView;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

        try {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            setContentView(R.layout.map_screen);
            mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.showmap);
            mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            final MapController mc = mapView.getController();
            mc.animateTo(new GeoPoint(((int) (latitude * 1E6) - 10),
                    ((int) (longitude * 1E6)) - 10));
            mc.setZoom(5);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MapCreate", e.getMessage());
        }
```

ApplicationManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <application
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:label="Andro Integration"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >


                <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <!--         <activity -->

<!--         </activity> -->

        </application>
```

Answer (score 1):

java

```
package com.manit.HelloGoogleMaps2;

import java.util.List;        
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;    
import android.os.Bundle;   
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;    
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;    
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;    
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;    
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;    

public class HelloGoogleMaps2 extends MapActivity {    
/** Called when the activity is first created. */    
@Override    
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
    setContentView(R.layout.main);    

    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);    
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
    HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable,this);
    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(30443769,-91158458);
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "hi", "I'm in India!");

    GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(17385812,78480667);
    OverlayItem overlayitem2 = new OverlayItem(point2, "hi!", "I'm in Ahmedabad, India!");

    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem2);

    mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed()
{
return false;
}   }
```

HelloItemizedOverlay.java

```
package com.manit.HelloGoogleMaps2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class HelloItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>{
private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
 private Context mContext;

public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
     mContext = context;
}

public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay)
 {
 mOverlays.add(overlay);
 populate();
 }
 @Override
 protected OverlayItem createItem(int i)
 {
 return mOverlays.get(i);
 }
 @Override
 public int size()
 {
 return mOverlays.size();
 }
 @Override
 protected boolean onTap(int index)
 {
 OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
 AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
 dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
 dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
 dialog.show();
 return true;
 }

}
```

Androidmanifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  package="com.manit.HelloGoogleMaps2"
                  android:versionCode="1"
                  android:versionName="1.0">
                <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

                <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
                    <activity android:name=".HelloGoogleMaps2"
                              android:label="@string/app_name">
                        <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                        </intent-filter>
                    </activity>
            <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
                </application>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
            </manifest>
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/mapview"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:clickable="true"
     android:apiKey="0Y2GRNdvsKsNO5cbkNKYcht3_0ASApwak-Q19Fg"
    />
```

string.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="hello">Hello World, HelloGoogleMaps!</string>
<string name="app_name">Hello,GoogleMaps</string>
<string name="mapskey">0Y2GRNdvsKsNO5cbkNKYcht3_0ASApwak-Q19Fg</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: this is the full code for android map example .I hope this helps.